# SharePoint 2013 - Change URL of document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I created a Document Library called Resource Documents. Would it be possible for us to set a friendly URL on this library so that files may be read with the following URL pattern...

```
http://site/my-resource-documents/...
```

rather than

```
http://site//Resource%20Documents/...
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you create a document library, it ask you the name for the DL. Once you give it, it will create library with same name and URL. You can change the name of the library any time but cannot change the url.
Here are the things i followed to create url accroding to my needs:

- Just go to a library trough 'Site Content'
- When inside the library choose on the ribbon 'Library' tab.
- Then select 'Open with Explorer'.That will open your SharePoint's library in Windows Explorer window.
- Navigate one folder up and you will see list of your libraries as folders.
- Rename required library's folder name as you want the URL to look like.
- Close the windows and refresh the browser or go back to home page and browse the library again.

Credit go to this person long time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904944/change-sharepoint-library-url

Comment: That works!  Thank you for posting the solution and the credit of source.

Answer (score 8):

Steps:

1. Open SharePoint Designer
2. Navigate to All Files.
3. select your document library and right-click library > rename.
4. Url is changed accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

In SharePoint Designer just navigate to All Files navigation node (not List and Libraries node), find your document library there -> right-click library -> rename. The URL will change to your new name.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PnP Powershell (useful for SharePoint Online):

```
#Set Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/p/"
$ListName = "Shared Documents"
$NewListURL = "documents"
  
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
 
#Get the List
$List= Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName -Includes RootFolder
 
#sharepoint online powershell change list url
$List.Rootfolder.MoveTo($NewListURL)
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Credit sample code to Salaudeen Rajack: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/09/sharepoint-online-change-list-document-library-url-using-powershell.html