# How to change Web Address for document library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I want to change the web address (URL) for document library.

Is there a way to achieve this? How?

Comment: Check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111524/sharepoint-2013-change-url-of-document-library

Comment: these might help http://blog.mastykarz.nl/4-ways-short-urls-sharepoint-server-2010/

can you be more specific on what you want? an example maybe? like what you have and what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the **internal name** of a list or document library using SharePoint Designer (SPD).

E.g. from `http://somesite/MyLib` to `http://somesite/MyLibNew`

Open the corresponding web with SPD, click on `All files` in the left navigation panel and rename the list / library by marking the entry and hit `F2` or select `Rename ...` from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is open the site in SharePoint Designer, navigate to "All Files". Search for the document library folder and right click rename.

Sound a little bit like an hack but unfortunately there is no other way to do this.

[Change SharePoint Library URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904944/change-sharepoint-library-url)

Comment: Hi all , I want to change the Web Address URL, you can see this in List Setting there is " List information Tab", Please help em exact solution.

Comment: Yeah that is the exact solution. You need to rename the folder of the list with SharePoint Designer.